# Observable vs asObservable()?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm new to Angular2 and I'm just curious to know That If I do a subscribe on `_showNavBar` or on `showNavBarEmitter` both works same(see below code i'm using). is there any difference?

```
public _showNavBar: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);
public showNavBarEmitter: Observable<boolean> = this._showNavBar.asObservable();
```

Answer (score 11):

`asObservable` makes the original subject inaccessible for subscribers. This way you can limit who can only subscribe and who can also emit values.

For this to take effect you would need to make `_showNavBar` `private` though.

Comment: Thanks, that is very useful but I have a doubt that above code is in a separate class that is Injectable.  if I make _showNavBar private, then I won't be able to emit values from another component(where I imported this class).

Comment: You can add a method like `addEvent() { this._showNavBar.next('someValue'); }`. But if you don't need or want that, then you probable don't need `asObservable` at all. I think it's good practice to always use it this way.